# What's the meaning of "peg" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> But it wasn’t until Ames pegged the actor for a network news anchor
>   that the show’s premise started to materialize. (quoted from Newsweek)

What's the meaning of "peg" in this sentence?

I looked up in the dictionary and found out it has many different meanings.

I guessed
"to classify; categorize" is the meaning of "peg" in the above sentence.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit on the answer. It does mean to classify or categorize.

> **peg**  *v tr*
>   4. Informal To classify; categorize: *I pegged her as an opportunist. Why do you have me pegged as the rowdy one?*

Usually this is used in a judgmental way, and is frequently negative. "Oh, I had you pegged!" is something said to indicate that the object of the statement has been found wanting in some aspect of character or capability.

Answer (score 0):

I don''t think *peg* in your sentence was used to mean "to classify or categorize".

Based on the full context:

> *Star Trek’s Captain Picard comes crashing down to Earth for his return to television.*
>
> One evening, as writer Jonathan Ames (of now-defunct HBO comedy series
>   Bored to Death) watched CNN, a thought occurred to him: Patrick
>   Stewart would look fascinating and striking behind one of these anchor
>   desks. Earlier in the year, Seth MacFarlane had approached Ames about
>   creating a show together, and MacFarlane had immediately suggested
>   getting Stewart on board. (Yes, that Patrick Stewart—of Star Trek and
>   stage-acting fame.) **But it wasn’t until Ames pegged the actor for a
>   network news anchor that the show’s premise started to materialize.**
>
> And thus Walter Blunt, star of the new Starz show Blunt Talk, was
>   born. Blunt — a pseudonym Stewart often uses, taken from one of his
>   first roles with the Royal Shakespeare Company — is a fast-talking,
>   hard-drinking British network news anchor with a penchant for fucking
>   up. Within the show’s first 10 minutes, he’s stoned out of his mind
>   and reciting Hamlet on the roof of a police cruiser, right after being
>   caught “just talking” with a prostitute.

It is closer to [mean](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peg):

> 6.To **indicate** or ascribe an attribute to. (Assumed to originate from the use of pegs or pins as markers on a bulletin board or a list.)
>   He's been pegged as a suspect. I pegged his weight at 165.

[Wiktionary]

> But it wasn’t until Ames pegged the actor for a network news anchor
>   that the show’s premise started to materialize. (quoted from Newsweek)

can be rephrased to:

> But it wasn’t until Ames indicated the actor would be a good candidate for (a role of) a network news
>   anchor that the show’s premise started to materialize. (quoted from
>   Newsweek)

Comment: To pin something down or restrict it is essentially what classification or categorization does. The meaning has broadened from literal "pinning" via a more metaphorical interpretation. Clearly the preposition *for* supports the latter view. To "peg something for" something else is to interpret it, which is a form of definition, which is a form of classification.

Comment: @Robusto I understand what you mean by the comment. But it makes a difference between using classify (categorize) and using *restrict*. Especially, in your example sentence, *restrict* doesn't work when used in place of "pegged" in "I *pegged* her as an opportunist. ". It sounds more like "compare/consider".

Comment: Still, it is a matter of perception, not actual restriction. How we view things.

Comment: @Robusto Absolutely. The original meaning of *peg* was used in the sentence. That's all I wanted to say. When you peg someone, he/she dosn't move.

Comment: But “peg” in that sentence does ***not*** mean “to restrict by signing a contract prohibiting him from appearing in another show”.  Here it just means “cast” or “considered him for the role of”. Basically I imagine Ames saying to himself, “Wow! What would it be like if we cast him as the news anchor?” and after that thought things started falling into place.

Comment: @Jim I've just read the full context and you are absolutely right. I edited my answer.